# inactive option not working for pam_lastlog.so

Tags: linux, pam, pci-dss

I'm trying to set up my system to lock out inactive users after 10 days. I'm using CentOS 6.x, and looking at RHEL manual, this is what I found:

```
To lock out an account after 10 days of inactivity, add, as root,
the following line to the auth section of the /etc/pam.d/login file:
auth  required  pam_lastlog.so inactive=10
```

So, this is my /etc/pam.d/login :

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth [user_unknown=ignore success=ok ignore=ignore default=bad] pam_securetty.so
auth       include      system-auth
auth       required     pam_lastlog.so inactive=10
account    required     pam_nologin.so
account    include      system-auth
password   include      system-auth
# pam_selinux.so close should be the first session rule
session    required     pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
session    optional     pam_console.so
# pam_selinux.so open should only be followed by sessions to be executed in the user context
session    required     pam_selinux.so open
session    required     pam_namespace.so
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    include      system-auth
-session   optional     pam_ck_connector.so
```

I log in through ssh as a user, and log out.

After that I set up the time 1 year in the future, as root logged in on TTY1:

```
# date --set "...."
# hwclock --systohc
```

I even reboot the VM, but still, when it gets back, I'm able to log in as user through ssh.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

> I even reboot the VM, but still, when it gets back, I'm able to log in as user through ssh.

Apples and oranges. You're editing the `login` file, but you're performing tests against `sshd`. The sshd daemon calls the PAM library directly with a service name of `sshd`, thus the identically named file is used.

In the event that you were not aware that the `login` file maps to authentication attempts by an actual *command* named login (which is invoked by your getty), `man login` is recommended reading material.

Comment: Then, documentation is not correct. I've moved line from /etc/pam.d/login to /etc/pam.d/password-auth, which is included at top of the login file, and now it works for SSHD, but it doesn't work for console logins. Do I need to have it at two places, although login clearly states 'include      system-auth'?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the up to date contents of `login`, `sshd`, and `system-auth.`